# Cron Jobs not running in Linux Mint 12

Tags: linux, cron

This is the content of my crontab -e file

```
#!/bin/bash
6 14 * * * /home/rishi/cront.sh
```

Also, the cront.sh file has only this

```
mkdir foo
```

I have been trying to make this work since the last 2 days. The cront.sh command works when ran from the terminal. But, does not work from crontab.

EDIT

It turned out that just editing the crontab -e using root
did the job. Nothing more had to be done.

Comment: concerning your edit: that should not have been necessary but could you post that edit as an answer anyway so this question is marked as answered?

Answer (score 3):

Under `cron`, there is no guarantee that your environment variables (most importantly `PATH`) will be set proprerly.

Try adding line like this at the top of your crontab:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Also, it would be good idea to use full path for mkdir:

```
mkdir /path/to/my/dir
```

Also, it would not hurt to make sure that your cront.sh is executable:

```
chmod +x /home/rishi/cront.sh
```

After that, it should work.

**EDIT**

**Generic method to debug crontab issues**:

- At the top of your script to debug, add a line:

  ```
  set    # this should print all environment variables
  ```
- Execute your script manually, redirect output to some log file1.
- Now, edit crontab to be something like this:

  ```
  * * * * * /path/to/my/script 2>&1 > /path/to/log/file2
  ```

Be sure that log file will be writable for your script.
Also, be sure that your script has executable bit set.

- Compare log file1 and log file2, paying close attention to env. variables. If they differ, use whatever method you want to set them to be the same. It could be adding lines to `crontab`, or using `export var=value` in your scripts.
- After that, there is no reason for this to not work properly.

Comment: I did all of them step by step. But it still does not work. Do I have to add something more to the PATH?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to first line

```
#!/bin/bash <--- remove this line
6 14 * * * /home/rishi/cront.sh
```

Is your script executable?

If it is not. Try running the following command in a terminal.

```
 chmod +x /home/rishi/cront.sh
```

An example of `crontab` format with commented fields is as follows:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    0        2          12             *               0,6           /your/path/yourscript.sh
```

Comment: I did not have that line before. It did not work then, so I tried adding this. This does not work too.

Comment: Your cron job will run 14:06 ?

Comment: I have been changing this to experiment. So, that must not be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
6 14 * * * sh /home/rishi/cront.sh
```

or 
add first line in cront.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or chmod a+x /home/rishi/cront.sh

Comment: I found the solution myself. Just cronted -e from root and it worked.